# STL and data from string to Vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Ok So I have tried everything.  I have the class below and I have a driver that will read a file and and take all the content using getline and copy it as a string.

In my driver I also have `vector<Seminar>`.

What I am confused about is HOW to put my data from the string to the vector.  Now I was thinking that maybe first I need to make a constructor etc for this to work?

I cant seem to implement it right.

```
class Seminar
{
    public:

        Seminar(int number = 0, string date = "yyyy-mm-dd" , string title = "")
        {
          Number = number;
          Date = date;
          Title = title;
        }

        int get_number() const {return Number; }
        string get_date() const {return Date; }
        string get_title() const {return Title; }

    private:
        int Number;     // Seminar number
        string Date;      // Date of Seminar
        string Title;   // Title of Seminar
};





enter code here 
    vector<Seminar> all;
    main()
ifstream InFile;
string Letter;
string File;
cout << "Type Letter from the Menu: "<<endl;
cin >> Letter;

if (Letter == "A" || "a")
{

    cout << "What is the file you would like to read: "<<endl;
    cin >> File;
    InFile.open(File.c_str(),ios::in);
    if(InFile)
    {
        string line = "";
        while(getline(InFile,line))
        {
            cout << line << endl;
        }
    InFile.close();

    }
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: I'm confused. I don't see any use of `vector`, and it's not obvious where you'd want to use it...

Comment: What does your string look like?  Have you already gotten from string to Seminar objects?

Comment: You need to write a method that takes a string (from your file, presumably), parses the data into the number, date, and title fields, and then saves the data into a `Seminar` object.  You could have this method be the constructor, or overloaded stream operator (`<<`), or just a regular method.  It's up to you.  You don't have to do anything special to put that object into a vector (using `push_back` or something, presumably) because the vector will use the object's copy constructor to copy it and your object's default copy constructor is sufficient in your case.

Comment: @keith.layne I added my driver so you may look at the string.

Comment: @indiv so I have the string correctly, I used added my driver, now to save it you are I saying I need a constructor correct?  And to add it to the vetor just use push back?  If so...thanks

Comment: @user1072583 you still haven't shown what the input looks like.  Follow indiv's directions.  If you have no idea what he's talking about, then read your book, google, and search SO.  There are plenty of questions here that will answer *all* of your questions for this task.

Comment: what input its only saving any text into that string line!!?

Comment: @user1072583: I'm still not seeing where you're using a *`vector`*.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I have the vector declared ...vector<Seminar> but according to indiv i have parse the data from the string to my vector...which I dont get exactly

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should point in the right direction:

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream> 
#include<string>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> myStringVector;
  myStringVector.push_back("First");
  myStringVector.push_back("Second");

  std::cout<<myStringVector[0]<<"\n"<<myStringVector[1]<<"\n";

  return 0;
 }
```

And I think in your case you may need to do something like:

```
Seminar seminar1(<data here>);
std::vector<Seminar> seminarVector;
seminarVector.push_back(seminar1);
```

Comment: What will the <data here> will be? the string that I have copied all the data in?

Comment: So that depends on how you create instances of `Seminar`, which based on your declaration would be `Seminar seminar1(int, string, string)`. You can then store that in your `vector<Serminar> all`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a vector<string>, then use [push_back()](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/vector.html) to add values to it.

```
std::vector<std::string> foo;

foo.push_back( "hi there!" );
```

Comment: thank you very much but I have tried that but when I cout foo[0] I get an empty when I switch your "hi there" with the word line with is my string